# Return One Row Stored Procedure C# Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a conceptual Yes / No question.  I am executing a stored procedure that returns one row.  Is there a method similar to `ExecuteScalar()` that will allow me to populate variables directly with the column values?  Or is using a `DataReader/DataGrid/Dataset` the only process to do it?

Comment: I guess there is nothing like this. It is scalar or table, no row.

Comment: I think DataReader is the best bet. Executing a single "Read" method will give you all the row's values

Comment: Do you have access to EntityFramework or other ORM?

Comment: The key point is: do you want to set the properties on an instance of your own class? If yes then take a look to [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: You could also consider an output parameter for each value to avoid the overhead of a reader. Practicality there depends on how many columns you have in the output.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded!  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Whether its one row or 1000, you (or MS internal code) will use a DataReader.

If you're interested in super minutiae super performance, declare a whole bunch of "out" parameters and hydrate from that.

But 99% of the time, its not worth the headache (the out parameters that is)

Comment: I chose this answer over Steve's answer due to the fact that this confirmed my question based on my skill level. As my skill/knowledge improve I hope to learn how to implement Steve's answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class called User where the properties of the class match directly the field names returned by your stored procedure. If this is the case, then directly from the [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) examples

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public string Account {get;set;}
    public string Pass {get;set;}
    ......
}

using(SqlConnection cnn = GetConnection())
{
    User u = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1}, 
              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();

    ......
}
```